# Guid into controller from View?

Tags: c#, asp.net, model-view-controller, asp.net-core

This code:

```
       public async Task<JsonResult> GetLatLong(int? id)
        {
            if (id == null)
            {
                throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(id));
            }
            //Guid idGuid;
            //Guid.TryParse(id, out idGuid);
            var flightData = await _context.FlightData.SingleOrDefaultAsync(m => m.ID == id);
            var returnedData = new
            {
                id,
                latitude = flightData.Latitude,
                longitude = flightData.Longitude
            };
            return Json(returnedData);
        }
```

works fine from the view if I use an `int` for the `id` data type. I tried changing the `Guid`:

```
       public async Task<JsonResult> GetLatLong(Guid? id)
        {
            if (id == null)
            {
                throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(id));
            }
            //Guid idGuid;
            //Guid.TryParse(id, out idGuid);
            var flightData = await _context.FlightData.SingleOrDefaultAsync(m => m.ID == id);
            var returnedData = new
            {
                id,
                latitude = flightData.Latitude,
                longitude = flightData.Longitude
            };
            return Json(returnedData);
        }
```

(also the model) and it then doesn't get called.

the view code is like this:

```
    @section mapscripts {
    <section class="scripts">
        <script type="text/javascript">
            $(document).ready(function() {
                Initialize();
            });

            function Initialize() {

                var dataObject = { id: @Html.ViewData.Model.ID};
                //var dataObject = @Html.ViewData.Model.ID;
                var url = '@Url.Action("GetLatLong", "FlightDatas")';
                $.get(url,
                    dataObject,
                    function (response) {
```

I simply can not work out why it doesn't work. I have reverted back to `int` and its fine. Its like the `Guid` can't be set in as `id`:
I even looked in the debug in chrome and can see that the guid is in the dataobject. Does java do something to my guid?
Lost!
Thanks
Johan

Comment: a Guid is a unique identifier created by .net. something like this: 9de31e20-3fcc-422d-a332-08d5f6cff646
dataObject = { id: @Html.ViewData.Model.ID}; become
dataObject = { id: 9de31e20-3fcc-422d-a332-08d5f6cff646
};

Comment: Is `dataObject = { id: 9de31e20-3fcc-422d-a332-08d5f6cff646 };` valid JS? What would **make** it valid? Let's have a different example. Let's say I had `var bob = Hello World;` - what would I do to make **that** valid?

Answer (score 0):

Wow I have obviously just been looking at this too long. Big thanks to mjwills for your pointer.

```
var dataObject = { id: @Html.ViewData.Model.ID};
```

changed to

```
var dataObject = { id: "@Html.ViewData.Model.ID"};
```

and the controller:

```
    public async Task<JsonResult> GetLatLong(string id)
    {
        if (id == null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(id));
        }
        Guid idGuid;
        Guid.TryParse(id, out idGuid);
        var flightData = await _context.FlightData.SingleOrDefaultAsync(m => m.ID == idGuid);
```

all works perfect now